# external HDD encryption with limited user rights on computer

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, usb-storage

I want to buy a new external hard drive to have work project files handy on the go.
Unfortunately the IT department has realised that security of external drives is an issue but they have not provided a solution by now. I want to do the right thing and protect the files I will copy onto the drive.

I've read that most vendors provide some form of encryption software with their drives to create 'containers' that are password protected. Unfortunately I remember at least one article which stated that the encryption algorithm of these vendor programs is often weak, badly implemented or even just fake.

I would prefer to use Truecrypt but as I have no admin rights on the computers I can't install and use it as far as I know.

Size of the drive should be 500GB or larger.

Any guidance in terms of encryption software and drive model/type is much appreciated.

Comment: I hope you've read [this article](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=non-admin-users) already about TC restrictions for non-admin users.

Comment: @Karan yes I've read this and that's why I said I would prefer to use it but it is not possible as I won't get IT to install it.